# How to add a OnClick listener spefic to this table?

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a quality-control for my internship and for that I need a table filled with buttons with ClickListeners. 
Now here is the Problem:
How do I add a OnClick Listener for each of the buttons?

The onClick method does not have to do anything really.
I have played with this table all day now.

```html
    <div id="Table"></div>
```

```
<script>
        function addTable() {

            var abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
            ];

            var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
            var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
            table.border = '1';
            var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
            table.appendChild(tableBody);

            var Y_Length = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("YWert")) + 1;

            for (var i = 0; i < Y_Length; i++) {
                var tr = document.createElement('TR');
                tableBody.appendChild(tr);


                for (var j = 0; j < localStorage.getItem("XWert"); j++) {
                    var td = document.createElement('TD');
                    td.width = '75';

                    if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
                        td.innerHTML = abc[j - 1];

                    } else {
                        var button = document.createElement("button");
                        button.innerHTML = "";
                        td.appendChild(button);
                    }

                    if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
                        td.innerHTML = i;
                    }


                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
            }



            myTableDiv.appendChild(table);

        }
        addTable();
    </script>
```

Comment: maybe this: button.onclick = myFunc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your button:

```
var button = document.createElement("
button.innerHTML = "";
td.appendChild(button);
```

Just add

```
button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

before td.appendChild(button)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this.

The first is to provide an event listener for every button:

```js
var abc = [
  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
  'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
  'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA',
  'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI',
  'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ',
  'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
];

function clickHandler(evt) {
  var btn = evt.target;
  var col = btn.getAttribute('col');
  var row = btn.getAttribute('row');
  alert('clicked on cell '+col+row);
}

function addTable() {
  var X_Length = 10;//localStorage.getItem("XWert");
  var Y_Length = 10;//parseInt(localStorage.getItem("YWert")) + 1;
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < Y_Length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < X_Length; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
        td.innerHTML = i;
      }
      else if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
        td.innerHTML = abc[j - 1];
      }
      else {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute('col', abc[j - 1]);
        button.setAttribute('row', i);
        button.addEventListener('click', clickHandler); // <--- Event listener for each button
        button.innerHTML = "";
        td.appendChild(button);
      }

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

addTable();
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="Table"></div>
```

And the second is to provide one for the entire table and filter on the event to make sure it was the button that was clicked. *This way uses a little less memory and a lot fewer event listeners. It also does works in additional rows or columns are added after initial render*

```js
var abc = [
  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
  'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
  'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'AA',
  'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI',
  'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ',
  'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
];

function clickHandler(evt) {
  var btn = evt.target;
  if (btn.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    var col = btn.getAttribute('col');
    var row = btn.getAttribute('row');
    alert('clicked on cell '+col+row);
  }
}

function addTable() {
  var X_Length = 10;//localStorage.getItem("XWert");
  var Y_Length = 10;//parseInt(localStorage.getItem("YWert")) + 1;
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.addEventListener('click', clickHandler); // <--- One event listener for the entire table.
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < Y_Length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < X_Length; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');

      if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
        td.innerHTML = i;
      }
      else if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
        td.innerHTML = abc[j - 1];
      }
      else {
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.setAttribute('col', abc[j - 1]);
        button.setAttribute('row', i);
        button.innerHTML = "";
        td.appendChild(button);
      }

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }

  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

addTable();
```

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="Table"></div>
```

Also, conciser moving code that only needs to run once outside of your function so it does not have to run each time the function is called.